# Default picture for iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

How shall I manage to make a default image for my iphone application that is large enough for the Retina screen? The screenshots I take with the Organizer in XCode is 320px x 480px, however how can I manage to get a screenshot twice as large? It is just a picture of the UINavigationBar, empty area in the middle and a UITabBar at the bottom with all content removed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the help, however I do not have a Mac/PC that has the resolution that I need to display the iPhone 4 simulator properly(high resolution, apparently). If you have, the answers given is perfect, however my solution was to download this:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/08/12/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/

and then resize components to 640px x 960px (minus the statusbar).

Answer (score 4):

To take a simulator screenshot, use Ctrl+Apple+C. Then paste the image into Preview (menu/File/New from clipboard) and save. That will give you just the screen, sans the iPhoney window border. If you want one with the border, use Grabber.

For a Retina emulator, set the simulator to iPhone 4 mode. Menu/Hardware/Device/iPhone (Retina). Just tried - it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run the app on a retina device and press both buttons at the same time to take a screenshot.

However, if you don't have access to a retina device, there is a great FREE program here: http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/ that can take screenshots directly from the simulator.  For Retina images make sure your simulator is set to iPhone 4 and that your screen resolution is set high enough to display it in Retina.

Comment: Or connect a retina device and use the organizer to grab a screenshot.

Comment: @Bolt, problem is that I don't own a iPhone 4(what a shame)

Comment: @theChristKent, does not a external monitor with 1280px x 1024px show the iPhone 4 simulator in "full size"? Maybe that is the reason.